# How to get binary representation of negative numbers in python

Tags: python, bit

When I enter `bin(-3)` it just shows `-0b11`.

Which is not what I want.
It just keeps that `-` sign and convert the number.
I want the actual representation of negative numbers.

Is there any method in python which does that?

Comment: Which one is the _actual_ representation?

Comment: Do you mean two's complement? To how many bits?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah two complement representation. Upto, standard 32 bit.

Answer (score 26):

Depending on how many binary digit you want, subtract from a number (2<sup>n</sup>):

```
>>> bin((1 << 8) - 1)
'0b11111111'
>>> bin((1 << 16) - 1)
'0b1111111111111111'
>>> bin((1 << 32) - 1)
'0b11111111111111111111111111111111'
```

**UPDATE**

Using following expression, you can cover both positive and negative case:

```
>>> bin(((1 << 32) - 1) & -5)
'0b11111111111111111111111111111011'
```

Comment: And even `>>> bin((1 << 64) - 1)
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'`

Comment: For bonus points, you can cover positive and negative in one go with bitwise and: `bin(((1 << 32) - 1) & -5)`

Comment: @cobbal, Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer according to you.